# Подготовка к собеседованию c#

Tags: c#, .net

Готовлюсь к собеседованию на позицию c# разработчика. Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты тестовых заданий.

Comment: их миллиард и для каждой компании для каждой вакансии, для каждого интервьювера они разные.

Comment: Если вы умеете программировать, то вам не о чем беспокоиться. Если не умеете - то учитесь. Более подробного ответа вы на такой вопрос не получите.

Comment: С опытом программирования проблем то нет, просто несколько в другой области

Comment: Очень за вас рад, но это никак не поможет понять, какие вам дадут тестовые задачи.

Answer (score 5):

**Такое, например, задание попадалось мне...** На мидла, кстати, позиция была.

**Написать консольное приложения для анкетирования**

При загрузке приложения выводится стартовое сообщение: “Выберите действие:”, нужно ввести команду для продолжения дальнейшей работы.

**Список доступных команд:**

●   cmd: -new_profile - Заполнить новую анкету

●   cmd: -statistics - Показать статистику всех заполненных анкет

●   cmd: -save - Сохранить заполненную анкету

●   cmd: -goto_question <Номер вопроса> - Вернуться к указанному вопросу (Команда доступна только при заполнении анкеты, вводится вместо ответа на любой вопрос)

●   cmd: -goto_prev_question - Вернуться к предыдущему вопросу (Команда доступна только при заполнении анкеты, вводится вместо ответа на любой вопрос)

●   cmd: -restart_profile - Заполнить анкету заново (Команда доступна только при заполнении анкеты, вводится вместо ответа на любой вопрос)

●   cmd: -find <Имя файла анкеты> - Найти анкету и показать данные анкеты в консоль

●   cmd: -delete <Имя файла анкеты> - Удалить указанную анкету

●   cmd: -list - Показать список названий файлов всех сохранённых анкет

●   cmd: -list_today - Показать список названий файлов всех сохранённых анкет, созданных сегодня

●   cmd: -zip <Имя файла анкеты> <Путь для сохранения архива> - Запаковать указанную анкету в архив и сохранить архив по указанному пути

●   cmd: -help - Показать список доступных команд с описанием

●   cmd: -exit - Выйти из приложения

**Заполнить новую анкету**

В анкете 5 вопросов:
1.  ФИО

2. Дата рождения (Формат ДД.ММ.ГГГГ)
3. Любимый язык программирования (Можно ввести только указанные варианты, иначе ошибка: PHP, JavaScript, C, C++, Java, C#, Python, Ruby)
4. Опыт программирования на указанном языке (Полных лет)
5. Мобильный телефон

Вопросы должны идти по очереди, после того как пользователь ввёл ответ, выводить следующий вопрос или ошибку.

*Все вопросы обязательны для заполнения.*

После заполнения всех вопросов, выводится сообщение: “Выберите действие:”, нужно ввести команду для продолжения дальнейшей работы.

**Сохранить заполненную анкету**

Анкета должна сохраняться в текстовом файле (txt) с именем, которое пользователь указал в ФИО, в каталоге с названием "Анкеты", который должен находится в каталоге приложения.

**Структура текстового файла анкеты:**

1. ФИО: <ФИО>
2. Дата рождения: <Дата рождения>
3. Любимый язык программирования: <Любимый язык программирования>
4. Опыт программирования на указанном языке: <Опыт программирования на указанном языке>
5. Мобильный телефон: <Мобильный телефон>

Анкета заполнена: <Дата заполнения анкеты>

**Показать статистику всех заполненных анкет**

**Нужно вывести в консоль следующие данные:**
1.  Средний возраст всех опрошенных: <Посчитать средний возраст всех тех, кто заполнял анкеты, целое число> (год, года, лет в зависимости от полученного числа, т.е если средний возраст получился 22, то вывести 22 года, если 25, то 25 лет итд)
2.  Самый популярный язык программирования: <Название языка программирования, который большинство пользователей указали как любимый>
3.  Самый опытный программист: <ФИО человека, у которого указан самый большой опыт работы>

Тестовое задание выполнить на языке C#, отправить исходный код и скомпилированное приложение.

Если сделаете, то приложите ваше решение в виде ответа на свой же вопрос :)

Кстати, если писать как настоящий мидл, то `Main()` должен быть примерно таким

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    UserInterface ui = 
        new UserInterface(
            new ApplicationServices(
                new DomainServices(
                    new UserRepository(),
                    new ProductRepository())));

    while (ui.ReadCommand())
    {
        ui.ExecuteCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: Выглядит не сложно) только вопрос есть: нужно ли, чтобы количество и данные анкет восстанавливались при перезапуск приложения? И если да, то в чем хранить список заполненных анкет? Upd. Хотя логично просто выдерживать названия файлов из папки и потом парить нужный тхт.

Comment: Я когда переходил с мидла C# в мидлы Java меня как тестовое задание просили написать небольшой аналог Dropbox - с клиентом, сервером, с наблюдением за папкой, сравнением файлов, синхронизацией - вот это было самое интересное задание на моей памяти, потратил неделю на изучение Java и неделю на решение задания, отпуск пролетел незаметно  :)

Comment: Да, выглядит не сложно, но стоит начать писать и потребуется достаточно количество времени. Плюс покажите свои возможности по проектированию правильной архитектуры приложения. Да, и юнит-тесты писать будете? Или как студент нет? Остальное на ваше усмотрение, это я про ваш вопрос.

Comment: Хм, консольное приложение на C# на middle?

Comment: @МаксЖуков да мидла, который должен в итоге работать над бэкендом ASP.Net

Comment: Спасибо за интересную задачку

Comment: @VitPetrov да, пожалуйста. См. добавил пример как все должно начинаться...:)

Comment: а чего не `container.Register<T, K>(...)` ?

Comment: @Bulson я заинтересовался этой задачей, и начал делать сможете пожалуйста скинуть готовый вариант для сравнения?

Comment: @Kioshilol сорян, у меня нет готового примера.

Answer (score 3):

На [METANIT](https://metanit.com/sharp/interview/) есть тестовые задания на понимание механизмов работы и основ C# и .NET платформы.

Из личного опыта, у меня было только одно собеседование, где давали тестовые задания по C#. Задания давались на дом. Дословно точно не помню, но суть заданий следующая

1. Реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки для разных типов (с использованием обобщений `generic`).
2. Реализовать стек (тоже `generic`).

Comment: это были задания для какого уровня? Выглядит как задача для студента ес честно.

Comment: @tym32167 да, задания действительно простые. Это на джуна. Гораздо важнее было пройти там устное собеседование.